# Knockout and JQuery for Ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting the Knockout.js submit binding to work.  I have the following element:

```
<form data-bind="submit: postPreference">
```

and my viewModel defines:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

  self.postPreference = function (form) {
    $.post("@{PreferenceR}", form.serialize(), function (data) {
      $.bootstrapGrowl("Your preferences were saved.", {type: 'success'});
    });
  }
};
```

However, I am getting an error which says that `form` is `undefined` at the call site for `serialize`.

Comment: Are you sure that `form` is `undefined`? `serialize` is a function defined in jQuery, so you should be calling it `$(form).serialize()`, not `form.serialize()`. Perhaps the error is `TypeError: undefined is not a function`?

Comment: @Nikola: The exact error was `TypeError: Cannot read property 'serialize' of undefined`.  I changed it to your suggestion, and now I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: @Nikola:  Actually, that did it.  You were right.  Switching to `$(form).serialize()` worked, and another problem caused the new error.  Make an answer if you want some points.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $(form).serialize()